# Circle to Polygon & Circle to Circle Velocity Resolution

Tags: velocity, collision, angular-velocity, software

I current am working a 2d physics engine, but have recently hit some bumps in the road.

Polygon to polygon collision and velocity resolution works without issue, but I am struggling to get working circle to circle and circle to polygon angular velocity resolution working as expected.

Each circle has 5 values related to movement: Position, Rotation, Angular Velocity, Linear Velocity & Friction.
Each node has 3 values related to movement: Position, Linear Velocity & Friction.

Here is a video the current version:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVHN9Or9b1g.
As shown in the video, the angular velocity of the circles do not change upon collision.

Here is what should happen upon collision:

[image]

[image: For example, if a car were to spin it's wheels on top of a sheet of wood, the wood would go flying in the direction that it's the tire is spinning.]

[image]

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How much physics do you know?  Are you familiar with the equations describing angular momentum, friction, impulse, etc.?  (We get a lot of questions here from people who want to build a "physics engine" without knowing a lot of physics, and to be honest the best answer in those cases is "you should study the first half of an intro physics textbook".)